# bind9, system-resolved and avahi

Tags: server, dns, resolv.conf

I've set `bind9` with DDNS and following the advice to disable `systemd-resolved`. All works fine so far.

I need to use `avahi`, but `avahi` complaining about missing `/etc/resolv.conf` (normally generated by `systemd-resolved` service.
Is where a manually way to suppress error messages:

```
avahi-daemon[]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
avahi-daemon[]: Failed to open /etc/resolv.conf: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Please list output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` in your question.

Comment: As described, didn't have a /etc/resolv.conf so fare, because this file normally comes from systems-resolved.service. I disabled this service because using bind9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your `/etc/resolv.conf` file manually. If an invalid symlink exists, remove that first:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then create a new `/etc/resolv.conf` file:

```
sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf
```

Edit this file, and add the following contents:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search <your-domain>
domain <your-domain>
```

I assume that you use localhost (`127.0.0.1`) as nameserver. Search domains are used for completing a given query name to a fully qualified domain name when no domain suffix is supplied.

Sometimes, I've experienced that `/etc/resolv.conf` got changed by the system, even if `systemd-resolved` was disabled. To prevent this, set the file to immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you want to edit the file, you'll of course need to unset and reset the immutable bit.

See here for more info: [`resolv.conf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolv.conf)